# per user traffic reports for website users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, analytics, traffic, google-analytics-api

We are planning to incorporate a traffic reporting system into our web application that our users can have a look over. Example: Our users might have profiles on our application and this will receive some traffic. Application users need to be able to have access to a traffic reports area where they can see all the detailed analysis of traffic like you would see on Google Analytics..

I'm eyeing at Highcharts JS to create the traffic charts etc. Can i somehow use Google Analytics to do reporting on per user basis?

Any inputs will be appreciated. (Application is being built on Ruby on Rails)

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use GA to get stats on a domain URL but you should just roll your own solution. I doubt that you need advanced geolocation for a users profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways this could be done.  First using custom variables.  You would define a custom variable such as "useraccount".  And then for each user you would assign a unique value.  Then when a page "owned" by that user is viewed, you modify the tracking code to include the unique value for the custom variable associated with the user that owns the page.  Then when you want to do reporting you would run your queries (using the Google Analytics API) and set a filter against the value for the custom variable corresponding to that user.

A second approach, as "Devin M" explained, is based on the URL (or page path).  If your users only have one page then this could be feasible.  But if they may have multiple pages this would get very tricky.  Because you would then be writing very complex queries against the API for the pages owned by that user account.

I have been building in "CMS Support" into a service I created called [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  EmbeddedAnalyitcs started as a service integrating with the Google Analytics API, allowing publishers to define charts against their GA data and then embedding them into their site.  As the product has matured, I have gained a lot of interest from CMS type developers who want a way to provide statistical charts for the users.  And we have been slowly building in support to meet their needs.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is suited to display aggregate data. Any attempt to show granular reports on a per user or per session basis may work for small amounts of data, but is completely unreliable and won't scale for a few thousand users. I don't see how Google Analytics would fit your use case scenario. I think you have to develop your own.

High Charts is just a charting library. I'd recommend [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). Good range of options and free.